# AVX512 not showing on Intel Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, intel, avx512, intel-tensorflow

I have a Windows 11 computer with an 11th Gen Intel Core i7-1185G7, which supports SSE4.1, SSE4.2, AVX, AVX2 and AVX512. The computer has no GPU.

I created a conda environment with Python 3.10, and ran `pip install intel-tensorflow`. According to the [documentation](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/guide/optimization-for-tensorflow-installation-guide.html), the command `pip install intel-tensorflow-avx512` should only be used on Linux platforms. It mentions that AVX512 is automatically used and enabled on PIP wheels:

> All Intel TensorFlow binaries are optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN), which will use the AVX2 or AVX512F FMA etc CPU instructions automatically in performance-critical operations based on the supported Instruction sets on your machine for both Windows and Linux OS.

However, when I start a new project that uses TensorFlow, the following message is shown:

```
I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
```

Therefore, I am not sure that TensorFlow is using AVX512 as the default instructions set.

---

#### Questions

1. How can I check that TensorFlow is indeed using AVX512?
2. If TensorFlow is not using AVX512, how can I force it to? Is it a bug that should be reported to Intel?
3. Is AVX512 really worth it in comparison with AVX and AVX2 when training a model in TensorFlow on a CPU?

Comment: *How can I check that TensorFlow is indeed using AVX512?* - One way would be to profile it with performance counters, e.g. under Linux, `perf stat -e task-clock,cycles,instructions,fp_arith_inst_retired.512b_packed_single,fp_arith_inst_retired.512b_packed_double  python my_program.py` to see if it used any 512-bit vector math instructions.  (That wouldn't catch any integer SIMD usage, though.)  Or interrupt it with a debugger and look for any of ZMM16..31 being non-zero. Or interrupt with a debugger a couple times to try to catch it in the middle of a compute function, and look for AVX-512 asm

Comment: I don't know TensorFlow specifically, but I'd expect that it saying only `AVX AVX2` is intentionally excluding AVX-512.  (Also, I realize my previous comment probably isn't useful to people not familiar with assembly language, especially since many Windows users wouldn't have a C/asm debugger installed in the first place, or know how to use one (e.g. to attach visual studio's debugger to a process not started from inside visual studio).  That's what *I* would do, because I know what I'm doing with such tools.)

Comment: You need to freshly [install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install) TensorFlow in your system. Please follow the steps given in [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows) link to properly install TensorFlow in your system.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be ideal but you could try WSL and run TF through there using the intel-tensorflow-avx512 package as a test.

It is supposed to be default in the TF windows package as well (no need to use the avx512 pip package), but I’m confirming that now. Will get back to you asap.